# Problem with Conda Installation: ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ctypes: The specified module could not be found

Tags: anaconda, conda, anaconda3

I'm on windows trying to reinstall conda after I deleted it from my computer. Every time I do, and then try to update conda using the "conda update conda" command, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ctypes: The specified module could not be found.
```

I get the same error if I try to use the command "conda install anaconda-clean".

I've tried to uninstall conda several times. I've deleted every conda and .conda folder in my folder, including the ones in appdata/local. I've removed conda path information. And I still keep getting this error.

Is there a way to fix this?